# Send SMS to Google Group

Tags: sms, group

I have a Google group of contacts setup (that is, it's a group I created and stored using my Google account). I'd like to send an SMS message to the group from my iPhone 5s with iOS 8. How can I do this with free apps?

In other words, I don't want to have to add people individually to the SMS message. I want to just choose the group (from a list of groups obtained from my google account), and the app will automatically add the members of the group to the SMS recipients.

Comment: SMS is at your carrier's rates. iMessage is free [aside from any potential data usage]

Comment: Not sure it's possible. You can sync your Google contacts, including groups, to iOS using something like [Contacts Sync for Google](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contacts-sync-for-google-gmail/id454390333?mt=8), but it still requires a whole bunch of taps to send a message to the group. Even the Google Hangouts app doesn't utilize groups created in Google Contacts.

Comment: I know hangouts doesn't allow you to use google groups, and shame on them for not allowing it.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Basically I have a dynamic group of contacts in Google Contacts which i want to SMS. Obviously i want to select this group on my SMS app so that it always uses the latest contact details.... cheers!